# Choosing an end point for Just Cause 2 (spoilers)

Tags: just-cause-2

I'm only at 35% completion, but I completed the strongholds, the agency missions (the story missions, after which you get to "mercenary mode") and I seem to have run out of faction missions.

There's still plenty to do of course - discover all locations, gather all items, swing statue heads from helicopters into enemy vehicles - but I wondering if it's time to move on (to the next game on my too-long list of unplayed steam games). So is this the end of the games "main" content?

**Are there any other "missions"? What do people usually do after this point?**

Comment: Achievements maybe? This is what I would do. I can't speak for anyone else.

Comment: I just mess around, [find new things to do](http://www.twitch.tv/gnomeslice/b/325079257)...  Getting a full 100% completion in the game [is actually impossible](http://justcause2mods.com/component/content/article/1-front-page-news/65-100-completion-now-possible-with-new-mod.html) outside of modding your game, and it still hasn't been fixed.  But if you're bored, JC2 has *a massive amount* of Easter Eggs you can go looking for.  Here's a [list of Easter eggs](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_Eggs) to get you started.

Comment: It is also a game where you can come back once in a while, have an hour fun and quite without being dragged out of some immersion etc.  Just cause mayhem or do crazy stunts etc. There is a multiplayermod coming: https://www.jc-mp.com/

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the day, only you can decide when you've had enough of the game. ;)

Agency missions, faction missions and the stronghold takeovers are the only structured "missions" within the game. However there are several actions that count towards completion as measured within the game. These actions are:

- Completing challenges (i.e. races, shown by the checkered flag icons on the map)
- Discovering locations (undiscovered locations shown by yellow dots on the map)
- Destroying Sabotage Destructible Objects
- Collecting resource items (Vehicle Parts, Armor Parts, Weapon Parts, Cash Stashes)
- Collecting faction items (Skulls, Black Boxes, Drug Drops - shown by blue dots on the map)
- Destroying Baby Panay Statues
- Assassinating Colonels
- Destroying pipeline stations (by hacking them)

All locations than can be discovered can be "completed" by performing the above actions within that settlement. All settlements will contain resource items, most will contain destructible objects, and some will contain a Panay Statue, Colonel or a pipeline (I think no more than one of these per location - certainly more than this is very rare). Completed settlements show on the map as the settlement icon with a green tick through the middle of it.

Completing challenges and collecting faction items does not count towards settlement completion - only towards total game completion.

Note that [a few glitches](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Just_Cause_2_100%25_completion_list#100_.25_glitch) mean it may not be possible to reach 100% game completion. The highest completion level required by a game achievement is 75% for the Perfectionist achievement.

In addition there are a slew of [other achievements/trophies](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements) that are not tied to the above criteria, such as for killing enemies in creative ways, driving all the different vehicles, flying under bridges and so on.

Comment: Could be included: https://www.jc-mp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You COULD go to the Mile High Club or just roam around the map with a Pell SilverBolt 6, or just grapple a car to a plane, or you could just unlock all the black market items, if you haven't. I also suggest killing ANYTHING, or just hack any vehicles, find any UNIQUE vehicles.